# Некорректная ближайшая точка

Tags: java, android, геокодирование

Еще раз помогите, пожалуйста) сейчас ошибок в коде нет, все определяется, проблема только в некорректности...Я сейчас в точке 55.898113,37.718918 , программа должна бы показать 55.894683,37.721857 , но показывает 54.463406,19.942433..в чем причина?

вот код ScreenOne

```
    package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ScreenOne extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.screen_one);
        }
GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint((formatLocation(null)), (formalLoc(null)), "hhh");

        private double formatLocation(Location location) {
                if (location == null)
                        return
                                location.getLatitude();
                        return 0;

        }

        private double formalLoc(Location location) {
                if (location == null)
                        return location.getLongitude();
                        return 0;

        }




        GeoPoint locations[] = new GeoPoint[]{
new GeoPoint(55.894683,37.721857, "точка1"),
                new GeoPoint(54.463406,19.942433, "точка2"),
 };






        GeoPoint nearest = GeoPoint.getNearestLocation(currentLocation,
                Arrays.asList(locations));


        public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView helloTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.station_name);
                helloTextView.setText(nearest.getName());
        }



}
```

а вот код GeoPoint

```
    package com.example.app;

import android.location.Location;

import java.util.Collection;

public class GeoPoint {

    public final double lat;
    public final double lon;
    public String name;

    public GeoPoint(double lat, double lon, String name) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.name = name;
    }



    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public GeoPoint(Location location) {
        this.lat = location.getLatitude();
        this.lon = location.getLongitude();
    }

    public static GeoPoint getNearestLocation(GeoPoint current, Collection<GeoPoint> locations) {
        GeoPoint res = null;
        float lastDisance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        float locDistance[] = new float[1];
        for (GeoPoint loc: locations) {
            Location.distanceBetween(current.lat, current.lon,
                    loc.lat, loc.lon, locDistance);
            if (res == null || locDistance[0] < lastDisance) {
                res = loc;
                lastDisance = locDistance[0];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }




}
```

Comment: на первый взгляд все правильно... попробуйте в лог выводить каждый раз lastDisance после перезаписи, и посмотрите, что выведется

Comment: этот код рабочий? проверки на null жесть какаято

Comment: @gcoder ,рабочий, если вместо обновляющегося местоположения вставить точку, то выдает все корректно

Answer (score 1):

Если судить по коду, то "показывает" все правильно: приведенная программа считает ближайшую точку к (0,0) а не от текущей локации.

Comment: а как тогда исправить?

Comment: необходимо имплементировать сам механизм обновления координат где-то что-то отсюда можно взять: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html